# How to crop image using opencv-ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, opencv

I wish to crop an image using the `opencv-ruby` gem, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you doing additional processing such as face or blob detection or do you just want to crop and resize images?

Comment: What have you tried? We expect you to show us you've attempted to solve the problem, or at least spent time trying to find a solution that didn't work for you. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to crop and resize you should probably use the `rmagic` gem instead (https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick, docs: http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/).

```
# note the .first, since read returns an array of layers/images
image = Magick::Image::read("my_file.jpg").first
cropped_image = image.crop(x_start, y_start, width, height, true);
cropped_image.write("my_file_cropped.jpg")
```

If you must use `OpenCV`, then this should get you there or close

```
image = IplImage::load("my_file.jpg")
sub = image.sub_rect(x,y, width, height)
sub.save_image("my_file_cropped.jpg")
```

Comment: hi soup, thanks for your fast reply, it's briliant answer. thank you, but actually a have another issue.

Comment: Hi Soup, I have another issue, maybe you have any idea this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065337/how-to-get-correct-position-x-y-of-detected-face-in-opencv-ruby . thanks