# How to get correct position (x, y) of detected face in OpenCV-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opencv

I need to crop detected faces with this snippet/ codes :

```
image = IplImage::load("my_file.jpg")
sub = image.sub_rect(x,y, width, height)
sub.save_image("my_file_cropped.jpg")
```

So I need x, y, width and height params, but I have no idea to get x and y params if my current codes like this :

```
op = OpenCV::CvHaarClassifierCascade::load(OD_CLASSIFIER_FACE_PATH)
img = OpenCV::IplImage.load("test.jpg")

detector.detect_objects(op) do |region|
  color = OpenCV::CvColor::Blue
  props.rectangle! region.top_left, region.bottom_right, :color => color
end
```

Really need help.

Thanks

Comment: That should be `op.detect_objects( img )` in your second code block I think.

Answer (score 1):

The co-ordinates you need are in the `region` variable which is an `OpenCV:CvRect` object. You can see what this does from [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/o/opencv-0.0.6/OpenCV/CvRect.html). The object directly supports x, y, width and height of the bounding rectangle, which should make your task quite easy.

Where you currently have:

```
image.sub_rect(x,y, width, height)
```

. . . if you have a variable `region` which is an `OpenCV:CvRect` object with the co-ordinates you want, you *could* simply use its properties:

```
image.sub_rect( region.x, region.y, region.width, region.height )
```

However, even better than that, the `sub_rect` method will take an `OpenCV:CvRect` object as a single parameter and do all this for you:

```
image.sub_rect( region )
```

So just insert this modification from the first block, and the call to `.save` into your `detect_objects` block:

```
op.detect_objects( img ) do |region|
  sub = img.sub_rect( region )
  sub.save_image("my_file_cropped.jpg")
end
```

Note this may write to the file multiple times (once for each face detected). So if you don't know how many faces there are in the picture, you may want to generate a new file name each time. Putting it all together, that might look like this:

```
require 'opencv'
include OpenCV

input_name = "test"
output_name = "test_faces_"

CLASSIFIER_DATA = 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml' # Or whatever

img = IplImage.load( input_name + ".jpg" )
detector = CvHaarClassifierCascade::load( CLASSIFIER_DATA )

face_id = 0
detector.detect_objects( img ) do |region|
  face_img = img.sub_rect( region )
  face_id += 1
  save_name = output_name + face_id.to_s + ".jpg"
  puts "Writing " + save_name
  face_img.save_image( save_name )
end
```